# custom delimiter for dat file

Tags: python, pandas

I've a `dat` file in the following format which I'm trying to load using `pandas`.

```
28::Persuasion (1995)::Romance
29::City of Lost Children, The (1995)::Adventure|Sci-Fi
30::Shanghai Triad (Yao a yao yao dao waipo qiao) (1995)::Drama
31::Dangerous Minds (1995)::Drama
32::Twelve Monkeys (1995)::Drama|Sci-Fi
33::Wings of Courage (1995)::Adventure|Romance
34::Babe (1995)::Children's|Comedy|Drama
```

Code

```
movies = pd.read_csv('movies.dat')
```

I'm getting this error

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 11, saw 2
```

Line 11:

```
11::American President, The (1995)::Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

I understand that it's because of the comma. One option I found is to skip these lines, which I don't want to. Is it possible to set newline as the delimiter here? Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: What is the command you are using?

Comment: Do you want to separate by | or by ::?

Comment: @DavidMasip `::` should be fine. later i can sort out the genre which are separated by `|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell

```
pd.read_csv
```

the separator that you want to use by doing:

```
pd.read_csv('movies.dat', sep = '::')
```

This should work.

Comment: this worked `movies = pd.read_csv('movies.dat', sep='::', engine='python')`.